# Haskell: Is there a more general key/value store class than MArray?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, haskell, monads, typeclass

I'm not sure if I'm underestimating the power of [MArray](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-MArray.html) or not, but for a lot of algorithms I implement, all I care about is that I have some data structure for storing key/value pairs.  Obviously the choice of data structure will impact performance, but it'd be nice to just write the algorithm first, and work on optimizing the data structure as needed.

What I'd really like is a typeclass like:

```
 class Monad m => MStore m k v where
   putAt :: k -> v -> m ()
   getAt :: k -> m v
   -- and possibly
   pairs :: m [(k,v)]
```

So my algorithm can manipulate things of type `k` without worrying if it's `Text` and I need to use a hashtable, or over generalizing and missing out on the array optimizability of `Int` keys.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `Data.Map`?

Comment: @Porges: It ties my algorithm to a particular data structure, with O(log n) access.  This isn't always bad (and sometimes, that'll be the data structure to use), but I want to be polymorphic over my choice of data structure.

Comment: Oops, I've misinterpreted the entire thing. Haven't had coffee yet. Oh well, at least in Haskell type classes are open, so you can roll your own and add instances as you need them.

Comment: So you want to change the data structure used based on the key type? That's exactly the sort of thing [data families](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families) are meant for.

Comment: If you're just looking for a generic type class so that you can avoiding committing to a specific container type, I don't actually think there is one for this. At least not one in common use. Getting a container type class API right is tricky, and isolated ones aren't very satisfying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to echo the comments, there really isn't such a thing in common use. A quick & dirty solution is to define putAt, getAt, and pairs locally as aliases to appropriate functions on your current data structure of choice. Then you can just swap to a new data structure by redefining the functions (and if you use a type alias for your data structure, then you can use type signatures without having to redefine those either). This is just an abstract-data-type by convention on the fly. You can switch to a newtype to enforce the adt properly if you like.

Note that the edison library (based on Okasaki's work on functional data structures) attempts to provide a general containers API, but the API is really only implemented for the structures provided by edison: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/EdisonAPI

Comment: This covers pretty much everything I would have suggested. The `newtype` approach should be pretty effective to make sure you keep everything else independent of the specific type used.

Comment: Thanks!  I still have difficulty telling the difference between "this isn't yet in haskell's libraries" and "you're not looking in the right place", so this is good enough for me.